# Tudor or Jacobean plays that are sequels to a Shakespeare play?

Tags: william-shakespeare, theater, sequel, english-renaissance-theater

William Shakespeare wrote around 40 plays (depending on how the Shakespeare canon is defined). Except for some of his history plays (*Henry IV*, *Henry VI*) and possibly *The Merry Wives of Windsor* (not a real sequel of *Henry IV Part 2* but another play involving Falstaff) Shakespeare did not write any continuations or sequels to any of his own plays. Marlowe, by contrast, wrote [*Tamburlaine the Great*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamburlaine) as a two-part play. But what about **plays by other dramatists that continue the plot of a Shakespeare play**? Do any such plays exist?

(I am excluding history plays from this question; there are history plays by several contemporaries of Shakespeare that tackle the same material—often based on Holinshed's *Chronicles*—in a different way.)

Note that the [Jacobean period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_literature#Jacobean_period:_1603.E2.80.9325) ended in 1625 with the death of King James, i.e. nine years after Shakespeare's death. Although the works I am looking for may have been written during Shakespeare's lifetime, I expect that the number of such works is very low.

Comment: This is kind of a request for "lists of things" as written. Can you [edit]?

Comment: @EJoshuaS English Renaissance theatre is the main type of literature I read or read about nowadays and I know of only one play that fits the bill at the moment. Technically, a list of one is still a list, but it is not a "potentially open-ended list" due to all the restrictions I wrote up in the question.

Comment: I think this is more of a "Do any exist?", not a "List all things" question, so it's still on-topic

Comment: @Riker Indeed, that is literally what the question asks: "Do any such plays exist?"

Comment: I retracted my CV and upvoted BTW.

Comment: Going to presume you know about Love's Labours Won and feel the sketchy information available isn't worth an answer?

Comment: @MattThrower Off the top of my head, the info about *Love's Labours Won* is very sketchy indeed. I'll look it up again, though.

Comment: Merry Wives of Windsor is a "continuation" of Henry IV parts 1 and 2, though it's not exactly clear where it fits into the continuum. Those are history plays, but Falstaff is a purely fictional character and Merry Wives is not a history play.

Comment: @JoshuaEngel *The Merry Wives of Windsor* is by Shakespeare, isn't it? My question asks for continuations by other dramatists.

Comment: That's correct. I mentioned it on context of the assertion that "Shakespeare did not write any continuations or sequels to any of his own plays".

Comment: @JoshuaEngel Ah, I missed the fact that you were commenting on a statement in my question. I have fixed that now.

Comment: The *Henry VI* plays aren't a continuation or a sequel of the *Richard II*, *Henry IV*, and *Henry V* plays, surely? They were written earlier, IIRC. The first tetralogy is the three parts of *Henry VI* and *Richard III*; the second tetralogy is *Richard II* through *Henry V*. I don't quite see how plays written earlier can be considered continuations of plays written later. They're not even after-the-fact prequels à la *The Hobbit* in that there doesn't seem to be any conscious effort by Shakespeare to shape the later plays in the light of the earlier ones.

Comment: Perhaps there's a case to be made for Shakespeare's own *Antony and Cleopatra* as a continuation of *Julius Caesar*, but there too, the thematic continuity seems scant.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, the only Elizabethan or Jacobean play that is a sequel to a Shakespeare play is [***The Woman's Prize, or the Tamer Tamed***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Woman%27s_Prize) by John Fletcher, a play that was first performed in 1609 – 1610. The play is a mock sequel to Shakespeare's [*The Taming of the Shrew*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Taming_of_the_Shrew). In *The Taming of the Shrew*, Petrucio "tames" Katharina. In Fletcher's "sequel", Petruchio is a widower again and remarries, but this time he is the one who gets "tamed" by his wife Maria. The play is also interesting for other reasons: its performance was prohibited for some time by the Master of the Revels until some adaptations were made, and it has survived in manuscript form (unlike any of Shakespeare's plays, unless you count Shakespeare's presumed contribution to *Thomas More*).

I also looked at the description of Ben Jonson's masque [*Oberon, the Faery Prince*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberon,_the_Faery_Prince) (performed in January 1611), but apart from the character Oberon, it has too little in common with Shakespeare's [*A Midsummer Night's Dream*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Midsummer_Night%27s_Dream) to count as a sequel.